# ionic app is running on wifi but not on dual sim internet connection

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing ionic app which use internet connection for its rest api.
I have given all sort of permission like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and also allow-access-controll to * which I read in some article but that was of no use for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors are showing in the error log? It's possible that you need to include the [whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)

Comment: @TheBosZ I have add whitelist plugin.It is not giving any error just when I am checking $cordovaNetwork.isOnline it is giving false